# Union list of pyspark dataframes

Tags: pyspark

Let's say I have a list of pyspark dataframes: `[df1, df2, ...]`, what I want is to union them (so actually do `df1.union(df2).union(df3)...`. What's the best practice to achieve that?

Comment: My solution would be as follows:

   all_dfs = [df1, df2, ...]
   final_dfs = functools.reduce(DataFrame.union, [df for df in all_dfs])

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you could use the `reduce` and pass the `union` function along with the list of dataframes.

```py
import pyspark
from functools import reduce

list_of_sdf = [df1, df2, ...]
final_sdf = reduce(pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.unionByName, list_of_sdf)
```

the `final_sdf` will have the appended data.

Answer (score 6):

When some dataframes have missing columns, use a partially applied function:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

# Union dataframes by name (missing columns filled with null) 
union_by_name = partial(DataFrame.unionByName, allowMissingColumns=True)
df_output = reduce(union_by_name, [df1, df2, ...])
```

Comment: This works, partial needs to be imported from functools for it to work
```from functools import partial```